# In App purchase getting Blank Sku details list

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription, onskudetailsresponce

I have create an app for In App purchase,
i have tested it works fine getting sku details list
but when run app in debug mode the getting blank Sku details list
do not know why i am unable find that issue,
I uploaded the app (in production )on play store and check for getting price it works fine
but some my users are getting blank list of sku detail.
is there any restriction for country specific (just guessing because i am unable to find that issue at my side everything works fine )
if any expert here know please help

Answer (score 1):

Your debug version must have exactly the same package as the release version, otherwise Play Store considers it a different app.

Answer (score 0):

It should be some of the prerequisites below are not satisfied. Read this [article](https://bewaters.me/limxtop/2023/11/11/Google-Play-Store-In-App-Billing/) for more information.

1. Upload the application to Closing Testing, no need to publish at this stage. (Internal Testing may be sufficient, but not verified).
2. Create SKUs, note that the ID should match the ID of the application request.
3. Add the tester's mailbox, which is the Google account login to the device to test the app SKU.
4. Switch License Respond to LICENSED (Path: play console homepage -> Setup -> License testing).
5. The Application ID for uploading Closing Testing needs to be the same as the Application ID for local debugging.